# Converting an Observable to a Flowable with backpressure in RxJava2

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I am observing the lines produced by a `NetworkResource`, wrapping it in an `Observable.create`. Here is the code, missing try/catch and cancellation for simplicity:

```
fun linesOf(resource: NetworkResource): Observable<String> =
        Observable.create { emitter ->
            while (!emitter.isDisposed) {
                val line = resource.readLine()
                Log.i(TAG, "Emitting: $line")
                emitter.onNext(line)
            }
        }
```

The problem is that later I want to turn it into a `Flowable` using `observable.toFlowable(LATEST)` to add backpressure in case my consumer can't keep up, but depending on how I do it, the consumer stops receiving items after item 128.

**A)** this way everything works:

```
val resource = ...
linesOf(resource)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.LATEST)
    .subscribe { Log.i(TAG, "Consuming: $it") }
```

**B)** here the consumer gets stuck after 128 items (but the emitting continues):

```
val resource = ...
linesOf(resource)
    .toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.LATEST)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe { Log.i(TAG, "Consuming: $it") } // <-- stops after 128
```

In option **A)** everything works without any issues, and I can see the `Emitting: ...` log side by side with the `Consuming: ...` log.

In option **B)** I can see the `Emitting: ...` log message happily emitting new lines, but I stop seeing the `Consuming: ...` log message after item 128, even though the emitting continues.

**Question**: Can someone help me understand why this happens?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you are using the wrong type and wrong operator. Using `Flowable` removes the need for conversion. Using `Flowable.generate` gets you backpressure:

```
Flowable.generate(emitter -> {
    String line = resource.readLine();
    if (line == null) {
        emitter.onComplete();
    } else {
        emitter.onNext(line);
    }
});
```

Second, the reason your version hangs is due to a same pool deadlock caused by `subscribeOn`. Requests from downstream are scheduled behind your eager emission loop and can not take effect, stopping the emission at the default 128 elements. Use [`Flowable.subscribeOn(scheduler, false)`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html#subscribeOn-io.reactivex.Scheduler-boolean-) to avoid this case.

Comment: Hey akarnokd, thank you for your answer. What interested me was the reason (I want to understand the internal mechanics hehe). I know that it would be easier to just use `Flowable.generate` but if I understand correctly, that way would effectively behave similar to a `BUFFER` strategy? I wish to be able to choose the strategy (maybe `DROP`, maybe no backpressure at all) when I subscribe. Is this approach correct?

Comment: `Flowable.generate` will emit based on demand and not buffer or lose anything. You can apply one of the `onBackpressureXXX` operators to get a different behavior.